# It is possible to fetch user/mailbox type using Microsoft graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to get informations about user/mailbox type (regular, distribution list, shared mailbox, alias) using the Microsoft graph API. I tried using the `/users` endpoint but I see there is no field with such info. Is there any way of doing this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That information is only available from Exchange PowerShell (Get-Mailbox), which isn't yet available via Graph.  You can get a list of groups (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and a list of users (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).  I don't know if that will work for your purposes.